text doesnt show on toolbar button
tbb[0].iBitmap = 0;
tbb[0].idCommand = TB_TEST1;
tbb[0].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
tbb[0].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON| TBSTYLE_AUTOSIZE| TBSTYLE_LIST|TBSTYLE_FLAT;
tbb[0].dwData = 0;
tbb[0].iString = (INT_PTR)L"aaaaaaaButton Text";

when i increase sentence length button gets bigger as well but text still doesn't show
i've tried
TBBUTTONINFOA tbInfo;

tbInfo.cbSize = sizeof(TBBUTTONINFO);
tbInfo.dwMask = TBIF_TEXT;
tbInfo.pszText = (LPSTR)"Savevjgfjygfy As";

SendMessage(hwndtb, TB_SETBUTTONINFO, (WPARAM)TB_TEST1, (LPARAM)&tbInfo);

but doesn't work

when i created toolbar with createwindowex adding this TBSTYLE_LIST|TBSTYLE_FLAT in style solved it.
